# What is a List ? [JavaScript interview question]

Tags: javascript, data-structures

What exactly is a "List" in JavaScript?

I got asked this question and I'm a professional of five years but this made me fumble.

I understand Arrays, Stacks, Queues, even Linked Lists.

But isn't a List just an Array in JavaScript? Because then I got asked what the difference between a List and an Array was, and I said no difference - and never got to know if that was right.

I understand the differences between the data structures List and Array in C# and Python but I don't get this one for JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript does not have an explicit list type. An array is about the closest you can get, as they are abstracted somewhat from array types in traditional compiled languages. They're more like the Java `ArrayList` type.

Comment: Try googling and let me know if you can find a definition for "List" data type in JavaScript @MrPizzaGuy

Comment: I have for about a decade respected the work of Nicholas Zakas, whose reference (if you can call it that) on JavaScript and, more to the point, data structures such as lists, can be found here - [N Zakas- Computer Science in JavaScript](https://github.com/humanwhocodes/computer-science-in-javascript). This might be of value too [JavaScript Data Structures at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: "What's the difference between a List and an Array in JavaScript" is a dumb question, really; it's a matter of semantics. Arrays can grow and shrink and do so automatically. Actually a better comparison is the Clojure vector type (which is probably *mostly* an `ArrayList` internally).

Comment: there is no list object in JS

Comment: @MisterJojoYes, but in practice for many purposes an array is very much like a list. We don't know what the interviewer had in mind, and in general it's unwise to presume that interview questions are crafted from a standing of significant authority.

Comment: That was the very first question I was asked and I had been really confused with it. Of course, fell for a trick question. :(

Comment: A `List` in JavaScript is whatever you define it to be. It is a question with actually no correct answer.

Comment: @Yishmeray I had read those which is what prompted me to ask this here.  Nowhere did I find a definition about "List". It was either a trick question, or the interviewer probably interchangeably used the term list and array - which I can understand if you coded in multiple languages.

Comment: Pet interview questions are like as@$^holes, everybody has one.

Comment: on the other hand, javascript arrays  have nothing to do with arrays in C# or Python.

Comment: Array: Limited sequence of typed variables. List: Unlimited sequence of typed or untyped variables. So there's no array in javascript, and a javascript array is actually a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the downvotes ... it was indeed a dumb question, I think I should have known that Lists weren't a type in JavaScript and tackle the dumb question that way.

For anyone this may prove useful: For front-end engineer interviews, make sure you know that JavaScript is a dynamic language, meaning the data structures are very different from static typed languages like C and Java, and even have different meanings in Python even though Python is a dynamically typed language similar to JavaScript.